# Slider with ACF field-type 'Image'

Tags: wordpress, slider, carousel, advanced-custom-fields

For a portfolio page, I have created a custom post type for each reference called “referenzen”. Since I need more than one image per reference (displayed in different ways), I have created some custom post types.
Now, on the front page, I want to display the newest references in a slider (kind of this type, exmple 4: http://www.wpcue.com/wordpress-plugins/advanced-post-slider/template-one/).

I tried to use some plugins, but there just created for regular post thumbs.

For now, I’m having the following code to display the latest 3 references.

```
<section class="entry-content cf" itemprop="articleBody">
 <?php query_posts( array (
      'post_type' => 'referenzen',
      'posts_per_page' => 4 // minus 1
 )); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <?php 
      $image = get_field('bg');
      if( !empty($image) ): ?>
           <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></a>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Now I need to bring this into some slider/carousel…

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Try: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show posts in the form of slider/carousel, please follow below steps 
    1. Please download bxslider.js & include it in header.php of your theme file like below - 
        `<script src="your-theme-directory-path/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>`

2. Make sure that field you have created to upload image is of image type with "Image Object" option.
3. Correct Your code as below -

   'referenzen',
             'posts_per_page' => 4 // minus 1
       
        )); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

   ```
    <?php 
         $image = get_field('bg');
         if( !empty($image) ): ?>
          <li>    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></a></li>
         <?php endif; ?>
         <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>  

   </ul>
   ```
4. Add below Javascript code in the footer.php

   ```
       jQuery('.slider2').bxSlider({
           slideWidth: 350,
           minSlides: 1,
           maxSlides: 1,
           slideMargin: 5
         });
       </script>
   ```